# What is the best IBMQ provider to South America?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, ibm-q-experience

What is the best option for South America Brazil to configure: `provider.get_backend ('')`, because `melbourne_16` is very slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The names of the chips are (sadly) not where they are actually located. I would recommend using `least_busy` to find the provider with the shortest queue so that you can have your results returned to you as fast as possible. This can be done as follows

```
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
device = least_busy(provider.backends(simulator=False))
```

There are many people using the devices, and so your jobs get placed in a queue, which is why it can take a while for results to come back

However, if you really don't want to wait, you can use a `NoiseModel` with the simulator to replicate real noise, as if you were to run your circuit on a real device. An example of how to do this can be seen [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/aer_noise.html),

Comment: Thanks @ met 927 your answers helped me a lot.
I'll test it, and send the results. Thank you